# Query Entity Framework including records that have not been committed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

Is it possible to query the context, make a change to an entity, and then re-query the context and get a result set back that includes the changed entity without doing a savechanges?  (I don't want to savechanges because I may want to rollback)

I know I can get the changes back by using GetObjectStateEntries, but I'm interested in the entire dataset.. not just the changed entities.

I think the only way to do this is with a savechanges, but wrap a transactionscope around everything so that I can do a rollback if my condition is not met.  Or am I missing something easier?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need access to the new set before you commit? Are you trying to do some sort of validation on to prevent duplication or something else that requires you compare the inserted/modified entities with all other entities in the set?

Comment: Basically yes.  It's not so much that I want to prevent a commit but that I'd like to update another entity based on the condition of the current state of ALL entities(change and unchanged).  It's a business rule that is akin to workflow.  Unfortunately, the state can change in different services that I call (with a cached context) that don't .savechanges().  So tracking these changes is prooving difficult.

Comment: This sounds like an operation that could be performed by another service/application (or on another thread at least). Could you create a windows service (or a sql job) to handle the updates? Is there some reason it must be done before SavingChanges()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not merge the set of existing entities with those to be added? I tested this out and it seems to work- it doesn't account for Deletes though, but you should be able to get the idea:

```
// get the entities that have been inserted or modified
var projects = myObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
     EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified).Where(
          x => x.Entity is Project).Select( x=> (Project) x.Entity);

// get existing entities, exclude those that are being modified
var projects2 = myObjectContext.Projects.Where(
     BuildDoesntContainExpression<Project, int>(z => z.ProjectId, 
          projects.Select(x => x.ProjectId)));

// Union the 2 sets
var projects3 = projects.Union(projects2);
```

**BuildDoesntContainExpression**: you can't use contains, and therefore you can't do the inverse, with the EF for some reason, so use this method:

```
    private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildDoesntContainExpression<TElement, TValue>(    
        Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {    
        if (null == valueSelector) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); 
        }

        if (null == values) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); 
        }    

        ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();    

        // p => valueSelector(p) == values[0] || valueSelector(p) == ... 
        if (!values.Any())    
        {        
            return e => false;    
        }    

        var equals = values.Select(
            value => (Expression)Expression.NotEqual(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));    

        var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.And(accumulate, equal));    

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was considering this sort of approach as well.  Shouldn't there be an easier way?  I'm surprised this question isn't more common.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because this technically works.  Although, I'm certain there's a simpler way.  But you've put some great thought into this and deserve the points :)  Thanks!